# Angular2 response mapping with subscriber

Tags: angular, typescript

In my angular2 application, I do have `authentication.service.ts` and `login.component.ts`

**authentication.service.ts**

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post('/auth/loginapp', JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }))
      .map((response: Response) => {
        // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
        let user = response.json();
        //Printt the backend response to the console
        this.logger.debug('User '+ JSON.stringify(user));
        if (user && user.token) {
          // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
        }
      });
  }
```

authentication.service.ts calls to backend authentication services and get the response according to user input and save to the localStorage.

**login.component.ts**

```
this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.logger.debug("Login User"+ JSON.stringify(data))
          this.router.navigate(['register']);
        },
        error => {
          this.logger.error(error);
          this.alertService.error(error);
          this.loading = false;
        });
```

I am always getting `data` as `undefined` in `login.component.ts`. authentication.service.ts gets the response correctly. I need to get the response data to the login.component.ts. could anyone tell me the issue with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Observable `map operator` expect you to return something, and I believe you are not returning anything there. Usually you want to modify the data in a `map operator`. But in your case you are not. Since you performing an action outside the 'stream' one option is to use the `.do operator`.

You can use do instead...

```
.do((response: Response) => {
        let user = response.json();
        if (user && user.token) {
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
        }
});
```

If you insist on using map, make sure it returns something...

```
.map((response: Response) => {

        let user = response.json();
        if (user && user.token) {
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
        }
       return response;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, I tried with .do but it did not. if you do have good tutorials about this could you give me a link?

Comment: Nor sure why didn't work, but here are some docs: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-do